# sed variable in query?

Tags: bash, sed

The following command works fine for me:

```
sed -i 's/^\(DEPLOY_ENV=\).*/\1VAL/' config.ini
```

But I want to use a variable, I'm trying:

```
sed -i 's/^\(DEPLOY_ENV=\).*/\1"$1"/' config.ini
```

and

```
sed -i 's/^\(DEPLOY_ENV=\).*/\1${1}/' config.ini
```

Based on suggestion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10901576/773263).

How can I use a variable with `sed` in my bash script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, try this:

```
sed -i 's/^\(DEPLOY_ENV=\).*/\1'"$1"'/' config.ini
```

Of course, `$1` is the first parameter, not a variable, but you can replace it with `$variable`. Take care that your variable/parameter does not contain something that could be interpreted by `sed`, like a `/` character.